# Java- Trying to use "for each" with multidimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
       for(Floor floor: floors)//where floors is an ArrayList
    {
        for(Apartment apartment: floor.getApartments())//getApartments returns an AL of apartment
           {...
           }
    }
```

Eclipse says it can't resolve the variable floor in the 2nd for.

EDIT: Apparently it was because of what I had inside of the inner loop, which is this:

```
for(Floor floor: floors)
    {
        for(Apartment apartment: floor.getApartments())
           {
                for(int e=0;e<floors.get(q).getApartments().get(w).getFurniture().size();e++)
           }
    }
```

Don't know why Eclipse couldn't find the floor variable though...

Ok, this was really dumb from my part. It was because the most inner for didn't have brackets... Sorry everyone. I got influenced by Eclipse auto-correction.

Comment: Is the second for loop inside of the first?

Comment: Did you copy-paste from Eclipse, or typed the code again? Something tells me that you've got a semicolon after the first loop in Eclipse :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something wrong that is not in your posted code. This works for me:

```
private void run() {
    ArrayList<Floor> floors = new ArrayList<Floor>();
    for (Floor floor : floors) {
        for (Apartment apartment : floor.getApartments()) {

        }
    }
}

public interface Floor {
    ArrayList<Apartment> getApartments();
}

public interface Apartment {
}
```